# Getting the first element of an object handlebars

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I use for arrays : myArray.0 which works fine. But when it's an object myObject.0 doesn'twork.

Here is an example of the object I want.

```
myObject : {
    book1 : {
        title:"One",
        Author:"Someone",
        Date:"19/06/13",
    },
    book2 : {
        title:"Two",
        Author:"Someone else",
        Date:"12/02/10",
    },
    book3 : {
        title:"Three",
        Author:"Another someone",
        Date:"03/09/03",
    }
}
```

I want to do something like :

```
`<h2>{{myObject.0}}</h2>`
```

and I expect

```
<h2>book1</h2>
```

Any idea of how I can do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
{{#with myObject.[0]}}   
    ..what ever you want to do with that object in here
{{/with}}
```

In this scenario you must include [ ] brackets.

However, if you are trying to access a property of an object the square brackets are not required

```
myObject.0.objectProperty
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not exactly what I intend to do. Sorry for not being clear enough. CF edit

Comment: I change my javascript code instead of using handlebars. However, if someone has an answer, I'll be curious to know it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't do this is that the order of properties in an object is not necessarily preserved.
So, although you wrote them as book1, book2, book3, if the syntax you suggest were allowed then myObject.0 might return any of the 3 books.

See [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) for a little more depth on this.